# setTimeout runs only once instead of repeatedly

Tags: javascript

I want to make the div fadeIn and fadeOut after every 2 seconds, but the setTimeout function is running only once and hiding the div, but that is it. It is not doing it more than once:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Pyp1</a>
<div id="disable">
    Hello!
</div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#disable').toggle('fast');
    }, 2000);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7av7ehtd/)

However, when I write the same thing for the click event, it actually works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('#disable').fadeToggle('fast')
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpddna4n/)

I've tried searching around (in Stack Overflow as well) and couldn't get the answer, I tried the click approach and it worked, but that is not the result I am looking for.

Where exactly is the problem and how may I fix it?

Comment: setTimeout runs once, setInterval runs many times

Comment: @dandavis Damn! Seriously forgot about that, sorry, will delete the question to maintain quality, but one more thing: I've heard that after sometime, it actually stops working, setinterval, is there an alternative?

Comment: you can call setTimeout from the bottom of the function setTimeout calls...

Comment: that was a bit unclear, may you provide an example, or something?

Comment: $(document).ready(function FN(){  setTimeout(function() {        $('#disable').toggle('fast');          setTimeou(FN, 2000)    }, 2000);});

Comment: Also, please upvote my post as I am banned from asking any question(s), I can't live without Stackoverflow! Sorry...

Comment: Okay...thanks for that, you may still upvote it please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setTimeout runs only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867427/settimeout-runs-only-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because setTimeout runs only once, how can you expect it to run multiple times? Use `setInterval` instead.