# Why setTimeout put outside a function will not be triggered?

Tags: javascript

see these 2 example

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var mTimer=setTimeout(foo();1000);
</script>
</head>
```

Other example

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var mTimer;
function test(){ mTimer=setTimeout(foo();1000);}
</script>
</head>
```

In example 1, when we load the page the `mTimer=setTimeout(foo();1000);` won't run

In example 2, when we click button to trigger `test();` then this time `mTimer=setTimeout(foo();1000);` starts to run.

**Why `setTimeout` put outside a function will not be triggered when loading the page?**

Comment: try `setTimeout(foo, 1000)` instead of `setTimeout(foo();1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` definitely works outside of a function.

Unless `foo` is a function that returns another function, more than likely you want

```
// do this
var mTimer = setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

Instead of

```
// don't do this
var mTimer = setTimeout(foo(), 1000);
```

The difference is in the first code, a reference to function `foo` is passed to `setTimeout` where as in the second code, the **return value** of `foo()` is passed to `setTimeout`

---

Run this code snippet to see it work

```js
function foo() {
  alert("it works!");
}

setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

Comment: I changed to your suggestion but it doesn't work. can you provide other solution? setInterval is ok?

Comment: I provided a fully working code example at the bottom of my post. `setInterval` has different behaviour than `setTimeout`

Comment: I put your code into my jsp file it ran just 1 time only

Comment: When clicking Run code snippet, your code runs just 1 time only

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867427/settimeout-runs-only-once

Comment: ... `setTimeout` only runs once. That is exactly correct. `setInterval` will run a function, ƒ, on an interval...